# To change a type of an expression in select clause

Tags: sql, math

I'm using `Postgresql 9.2`

Suppose I have the table:

```
  id        date          click_count      registration_count
serial    timestamp         bigint              bigint
```

I've written the following query:

```
select date, sum(click_count), 
     sum(registration_count), 
     (CASE 
           WHEN (not sum(click_count) = 0) 
           THEN sum(registration_count)/sum(click_count)*100 
           ELSE 0 
     END) as convert
from myTbl
```

It works, but not properly. The thing is I need to get a double result of the arithmetic operation, but in the result it has `bigint` type. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `cast()`?

```
select date, sum(click_count), 
       sum(registration_count), 
       (CASE WHEN (not sum(click_count) = 0) 
             THEN cast(sum(registration_count) as double)/sum(click_count)*100 
             ELSE 0.0
        END) as convert
from myTbl
```

Comment: @canon It seems, no. I executed that query but the result is obviously incorrect.

Comment: @canon . . . The division might happen before the multiplication.